# Misalignment of GPX data layer on OS Map

Tags: openlayers, layers, gpx

I am new to the new structure of OS Maps.   I have added a map to my website

```
   var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.XYZ({
                url: serviceUrl + '/Leisure_27700/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=' + apiKey,
                projection: 'EPSG:27700',
                tileGrid: tilegrid
            })
        })
    ],
    target: 'osmap',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:27700',
        resolutions: tilegrid.getResolutions(),
        minZoom: 0,
        maxZoom: 9,
        center: [ 338084, 497501.6 ],
        zoom: 7
    })
});
```

and this works fine.  I am trying to add GPX overlays to the map to highlight walking routes and sometimes they align correctly, but most of the time are mis-aligned.  When mis-aligned they also seem to scroll at different rates to the main map when dragging the map..  Also they appear to be in a small "bounding box" as parts of the overlay disappear.

I add the GPX layers :-

```
claiffe = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
    url: '/media/walks/claiffeheights.gpx',
    format: new ol.format.GPX()
}),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: [0,0,255,0.5],
            width: 4
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(claiffe);
```

This is how the map should look

[image: Correct Overlays]

This shows incorrect overlay position.

[image: Incorrect Overlay Position]

Overlay route truncated at the bottom whilst dragging

[image: Truncated overlay when the map is dragged]

I've done some more investigation , and when the error occurs an extra overlay is created and transform is applied to this layer :-

```
<div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
    <div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <canvas width="1200" height="768" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);">
        </canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="ol-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        <canvas width="1500" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top; transform: matrix(0.8, 0, 0, 0.8, 0, 0);" height="960">
        </canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

When it works correctly only 1 "ol-layer" is present.

In the CSS there is a rule:-

```
canvas, img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

After removing the  "max-width: 100%;"   the layers line up correctly

Comment: You forgot to mention you are using OpenLayers for map display.

Comment: Apologies TomazicM...     I've also noticed that it may be related to the resolution of the Display used, so I am guessing it is some sort of scaling issue.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please add a screen shot

Comment: Does this happen only on some devices or browsers, or when using browser zoom?  If so do any OpenLayers examples such as https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-features.html or the OS example https://labs.os.uk/public/openspace-migration/examples/adding-gpx have the same problem?  Setting `pixelRatio: 1` in the map options might fix it.

Comment: Hi Mike,  pixelRatio:1 worked perfectly...  I am surprised this problem hasn't happened to other people...   Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mike It would be nice to post this solution as an answer, with maybe some additional explanation.

Comment: @TomazicM  It is not an ideal solution as fixing the pixelRatio to 1 will reduce the quality of the map on devices/browsers which are not affected by the problem.  I have only seen it on the default Android browser (with no way to debug) on old devices where newer browsers such as Chrome and Opera work correctly.

Comment: You didn't mention this about browsers before, although Mike explicitly asked you about it.

Comment: I had this problem on both Chrome and Edge on a new Windows 10 PC which is why I was surprised no one else had come across the same issue, PS the previous comment was from Mike

Comment: @Alan Sheers Do the examples I linked have have the same problem on your system?

Comment: @AlanSheers Ups, sorry, I overlooked it's Mike's comment.

Comment: @Mike, the examples you linked seem to work ok

Comment: Maybe there is something about the structure of your page or css which is affecting scaling of the OpenLayers map layers?

Comment: @Mike  I have tried to strip down my page but the problem still occurs, do you have any clues as to what I should look for...   Ps It may be a red herring, but I've noticed that unless the "map" div is specified with an absolute position in the CSS then the OS logo is positioned incorrectly vertically...  This occurs on the basic OSMaps tutorial too

Comment: That in itself does not seem to be a problem, but the need for `position:absolute` for the branding to work means the map div must either be full page, in an iframe or nested inside a `position:relative` container div on your page.  That could potentially result in the map inheriting a problem causing css setting from the container.

Comment: Thanks @Mike    I've done some more investigation , and when the error occurs an extra overlay is created and transform is applied to this layer.  See my edits in the main document

Answer (score 1):

When the device pixel ratio is 1 both the tile layer and the vector layer will use the same canvas (unless the view is rotated).  If you have a high resolution display or are using browser zoom the vector layer canvas is optimised and uses a separate canvas enlarged to use device pixels instead of css pixels (tiles cannot be optimised beyound their native resolution).  You would therefore need to exclude canvas in your map div from your rule:

```
canvas:not(#osmap canvas), img, video {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```